# How to Build Apps with Fixed Ratio For Foldable Device

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, android-layout, foldable-devices

currently I'm working with React Native platform and I'd like to adjust my apps for foldable device. Instead of making my apps full screen, I rather make my apps look like Instagram on foldable device. Is there any way to publish fixed ratio apps so it will look like this? Thank you in advance [Instagram on Foldable Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9v4QX.jpg)

Comment: Have you found any solution for this issue?